# Appium : Can it be used for cross platform application testing

Tags: android, ios, automated-tests, appium

I have one application that is developed using cross platform development tool. This app has same interface for ios(ipa) and android(apk). Can I write one automation script and run it across both the platforms i.e both for android and ios app.

Anyone tried this using Appium ? What are the locating techniques that need to be used for developing test scripts for cross platform testing. e.g by tagName, xpath ?

What are the limitations with appium for cross platform testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, cross platform means [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) right?

**Que 1:-**
Yes, [Appium](http://appium.io/) support to hybrid as well as native iOS/Android app.

for automation you can reuse same code for both iOS and Android(But take it with pinch of salt).
Please see [6th answer here](http://help.testdroid.com/customer/portal/articles/1507216-appium-faqs)

Check out this github link https://github.com/appium/appium.

**Que 2:-**

Locating elements :-
    you can use indexes, resource_id, text, and XPath also.

**1. Indexes** :- Suppose you want to get index of buttons. Appium treat specific types of elements as array.
              Start counting of indexes(button[0],button[1](http://www.sencha.com/) ... ) from top to bottom, left to right.

2. [uiautomatorviewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) :- connect you mobile device to desktop and launch your app.
   In desktop terminal use `uiautomatorviewer` command (please make sure you have all ANDROID_HOME path set for tools, platform-tools, build-tools and `adb devices` showing all attached devices list).

It will open a window, click on right most take a screenshot button. Hover on elements present on screenshot you will see all **elements by indexes, resource_id, text, and XPath**

**limitations** :- Appium is Little bit unstable till now.
                   Android 4.2+ supports to `uiautomatorviewer` while for lower version use `Selendroid`

for cross platform you need to change code `capabilities` based on your platform(iOS/Android) and device version and running platforms.

See blog for help http://swapnilvkotwal.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/appium-setup-ruby-sample-test-script/