# Click is not working with appium test is passing but no action is performed

Tags: java, android, appium

I want to click on logout button. I have tried following things to perform a click action

Using Tap

```
  WebElement logOut = driver.findElementByName("Log out");
            TouchAction act = new TouchAction(driver);
            act.tap(logOut, 1, 1);
```

Simple click

```
WebElement logOut = driver.findElementByName("Log out");
        logOut.click();
```

Press

```
TouchAction act = new TouchAction(driver);
        act.press(logOut).perform()
```

;

For Press its giving

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
```

Also tried

```
MobileElement logout = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByName("Log out");
        logout.tap(1, 10);
```

Which gives same unknown server-side error

Let me know if I am doing wrong anywhere.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Here is server log

```
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding Log out using NAME with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=Log out, INSTANCE=0]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"}}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"sessionId":"ad4afb54-6f6d-4a39-bb60-49e4cbbcc4bc"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/ad4afb54-6f6d-4a39-bb60-49e4cbbcc4bc/element 200 44.615 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"sessionId":"ad4afb54-6f6d-4a39-bb60-49e4cbbcc4bc"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/ad4afb54-6f6d-4a39-bb60-49e4cbbcc4bc/touch/perform {"actions":[{"action":"press","options":{"element":"2"}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":250}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getLocation",{"elementId":"2"}]
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getSize",{"elementId":"2"}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getLocation","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getLocation
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"x":-256,"y":932}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getSize","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getSize
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"width":240,"height":81}}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getLocation",{"elementId":"2"}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getLocation","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getLocation
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"x":-256,"y":932}}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getSize",{"elementId":"2"}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getSize","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getSize
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"width":240,"height":81}}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:touchDown",{"elementId":"2","x":-136,"y":972.5}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:touchDown","params":{"elementId":"2","x":-136,"y":972.5}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: touchDown
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Performing TouchDown using element? true x: -136, y: 972
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":13,"value":"Failed to execute touch event"}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"Failed to execute touch event"},"sessionId":"ad4afb54-6f6d-4a39-bb60-49e4cbbcc4bc"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/ad4afb54-6f6d-4a39-bb60-49e4cbbcc4bc/touch/perform 500 211.167 ms - 198 
> info: [debug] Didn't get a new command in 60 secs, shutting down...
> info: Shutting down appium session
> info: [debug] Pressing the HOME button
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\fission\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s f547bbb6 shell "input keyevent 3"
> info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
> info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
> info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Time: 82.744
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] OK (1 test)
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.SecurityException
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=21860, uid=2000, (need uid=1000) is not allowed to send as package android
```

Comment: Do you have access to any logs on the server-side  ?

Comment: @Berger No I dont have access

Comment: ""Log out" isn't located, plz try indexes, resource_id, text, and XPath also. Please check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/22856017/1665592

Comment: @Swapnil Yes I tried with xpath as well

Comment: Plz set android env Path and use `uiautomatorviewer` and see if indexes can help?

Comment: @Swapnil Index also not working. Actually there is no issue in finding locator. Test is passing but no action is performed after clicking

Comment: ok, so that means developer has defined `OnClick` even on some other field and it's not on `Log Out`. You need to find out exactly on what field click, user get singout. There might be some label, text (very close to `logout` button) on which click user get singed out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101760/discussion-between-swapnil-and-testing).

Comment: can you please attach a screenshot from UIAutomatorViewer or Appium Screenshot for the screen on which you want to access the objects.

Comment: @nullpointer I have added screenshot in question

Comment: ideally `MobileElement logout = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByName("Log out");
        logout.click();` this should work assuming the driver used in the AppiumDriver to execute the test.

Comment: @nullpointer I tried your solution test is passing but logout action is not performed

Comment: can you show us the appropriate code removing everything else that is not working

Comment: Tap is nearly fool proof. The only issue I've had with it is the duration which you have set to 10. In my experience, anything shorter than 250 is very fickle. Try 250 or higher for the duration (ex: `driver.findElementByName("Log out").logout.tap(1, 250);`) Also I noticed you are casting MobileElement.  Try initializing the driver with the MobileElements like `public static IOSDriver<MobileElement>` or `public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement>`

Comment: Did you check if you are in native_view or webview?? findout using driver.getcontext(),

Comment: @Pankaj I have checked with driver.getContext() before clicking its NATIVE_APP only

Comment: @econoMichael I have tried your suggestion again by casting driver. Its giving. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.

Comment: please paste the whole server log!!

Comment: @Pankaj I have added server log in question please check

Comment: Can you see if your desired element is present under some webview ?? if yes then you have to make app debuggable and switch to webview context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101872/discussion-between-testing-and-pankaj).

Comment: is any solution to this ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<WebElement> list  = driver.findElementByName("Log out");
for (int 1=0;1<list.size();i++){
System.out.println("clicked on "+list.get(i).getAttribute("name"))
}
```

This will give u all the elements index no with its name. From which u can click on the specific index eg:-`list.get(6).click();`

Answer (score 0):

If your click event is not working then probably your developer must have used some api like **patlab** instead of click event..

You should consult your developer whether he/she have used api like patlab or not

if so then ask your developer for the event name and you can trigger using jquery